# can you help me it wont display my rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

game_over = False

while not game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        sys.exit()
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0),(400,300,50,50))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to correctly format it. And describe problem below code.

Comment: you have wrong indentions - you have to `draw` and `flip` inside `while` loop.

Comment: You will never reach the code below the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Furas writes, the screen update code is not being called from within the loop.  Python uses [indentation](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) to designate code blocks, so if the function call (or other code section) is not indented to the correct column, it is literally  a completely different set of operations.

Since a piece of sample code is worth a thousand words:

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

game_over = False

while not game_over:
    # Handle user-events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True

    # Re-draw the screen
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (400,300,50,50))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```